# Curl экранирование &

Tags: linux, curl, unix

Нужно отправить Curl'ом POST запрос. Конечный запрос выглядит так:

> curl http://example.com --data
>   "test=test&link=http://example.com/?id=2***&***pg=2"

Обратите внимание на & после 2, curl воспримет его как отельный POST параметр, а мне нужно что бы этого не происходило.

Comment: curl вряд ли будет что-то воспринимать, это скорее сервер так воспримет эту строку. Квадратная скобка в конце имеет какой-то смысл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Применяйте URL-кодирование к парметрам запроса. В частности, замените `&` на `%26`